# How can i get the result from oci_execute()?

Tags: php, oracle

[image]

[image]

It gives true but when I use `oci_fetch($stmt)` it shows error.

> oci_fetch(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and
> fetch

```
$sql = "DECLARE
            C1  KTI_OPPL_DB.MH_ONLINE_PACKAGE_DB.TABLE_OF_LOV;
        BEGIN
        KTI_OPPL_DB.MH_ONLINE_PACKAGE_DB.GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV(C1);
          
         
        END;";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r = oci_execute($stmt);
   
while (oci_fetch($stmt)) {
    $nrows = oci_num_rows($stmt);
}
```

Comment: what result are you trying to get ? you are executing a procedure without output parameter . or is your procedure getting an output as sys_refcursor ?

Comment: This is the procedure defnition.I don't have any idea about oracle with php.GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV(P_LOV_RECORD OUT TABLE_OF_LOV)

Comment: that procedure will not provide any output result that you can get with `oci_fetch`

Comment: Can you please give the solution to get the result from this procedure or how I need to call the procedure.

Comment: I am putting an answer, but you can't get any result without changing the procedure

Comment: I don't have any access to the procedure.My client give the procedure with parameter to access the datas from the oracle db.They are getting the result in their machine

Comment: I edited my question with what the actual procedure is.Can you check that image which I added now to my question

Comment: I think that TABLE_OF_LOV IS A  user defined data type.So I tried $my_collection = oci_new_collection($conn, 'TABLE_OF_LOV', 'KTI_OPPL_DB.MH_ONLINE_PACKAGE_DB'); but shows errors oci_new_collection(): OCI-22303: type &quot;KTI_OPPL_DB.MH_ONLINE_PACKAGE_DB&quot;.&quot;TABLE_OF_LOV&quot; not found

Answer (score 1):

As I was telling you in the comment section, `oci_fetch` will not provide any result because the statement you are executing is not a sql statement, but a pl/sql procedure.

### How to use OCI_FETCH

> Fetches the next row from a query into internal buffers accessible either with oci_result(), or by using variables previously defined with oci_define_by_name().

An example using `oci_result`

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = 'SELECT location_id, city FROM locations WHERE location_id < 1200';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
    echo oci_result($stid, 'LOCATION_ID') . " is ";
    echo oci_result($stid, 'CITY') . "<br>\n";
}

// Displays:
//   1000 is Roma
//   1100 is Venice

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

An example with `oci_define_by_name`

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = 'SELECT location_id, city FROM locations WHERE location_id < 1200';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

// The defines MUST be done before executing
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'LOCATION_ID', $locid);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'CITY', $city);

oci_execute($stid);

// Each fetch populates the previously defined variables with the next row's data
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
    echo "Location id $locid is $city<br>\n";
}

// Displays:
//   Location id 1000 is Roma
//   Location id 1100 is Venice

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

In your case, you are executing a PROCEDURE which is providing as output a user defined type. In this case you might try `oci_fetch_array` to get the result of the procedure passed as an array of three values ( which is what you get from your output ). PHP and Oracle user defined types are tricky, so I'd try this ( **Adapt to your code** ):

```
<?php
  

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'BEGIN yourprocedure(:rc); END;');
$refcur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':rc', $refcur, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($stid);

// Execute the returned REF CURSOR and fetch from it like a statement identifier
oci_execute($refcur);  
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($refcur, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($refcur);
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: I tried this but giving oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact PL/SQL to create your type, we can only guess what TABLE_OF_LOV is.  Here is an example that shows getting records from a TABLE OF VARCHAR2, which seems a feasible guess.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$c = oci_connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/XE");
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

//
// Create a PL/SQL package that has a 'TABLE OF' OUT parameter
//

$create_pkg = "
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
        TYPE TABLE_OF_LOV IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(20) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
        PROCEDURE GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV(p1 OUT TABLE_OF_LOV);
    END mypackage;";
$s = oci_parse($c, $create_pkg);
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$create_pkg_body = "
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS
        PROCEDURE GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV(p1 OUT TABLE_OF_LOV) IS
        BEGIN
            p1(1) := 'one';
            p1(2) := 'two';
            p1(3) := '';
            p1(4) := 'four';
            p1(5) := 'five';
        END GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV;
    END mypackage;";
$s = oci_parse($c, $create_pkg_body);
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

//
// Call the PL/SQL procedure
//

$s = oci_parse($c, "BEGIN mypackage.get_vessel_type_lov(:bv); END;");
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r = oci_bind_array_by_name($s, ":bv", $array, 5, 20, SQLT_CHR);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not bind a parameter: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);

}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Output is:

```
$ php so3.php 
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "five"
}
```

You may find other solutions such as writing 'PL/SQL wrappers' in the *USING PL/SQL WITH OCI8* chapter on p187 of the free book [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I tried the code which you proveded.this is ths code which i used

Comment: $s = oci_parse($conn, 'BEGIN KTI_OPPL_DB.MH_ONLINE_PACKAGE_DB.GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV(:P_LOV_RECORD); END;');

oci_bind_array_by_name($s, ":P_LOV_RECORD", $r,  2000,2000, SQLT_CHR);

oci_execute($s);
var_dump($r);

Comment: But it gives error oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_VESSEL_TYPE_LOV' ORA-06550.I gave two images in the question can you check that

Comment: you have to declare `:P_LOV_RECORD`. It is an output variable